# Hot to call my own component inside modal Angular 12 and NGZorro

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to call my own component inside nzmodal. I have tried this:

```
<nz-modal
  [(nzVisible)]="isVisible"
  nzTitle="Create relation"
  (nzOnCancel)="handleCancel()"
  (nzOnOk)="handleOk()">

  <app-label-relation-create>
  </app-label-relation-create>
</nz-modal>
```

Inside label relation create I have form.

Have I add some reference in routing module? Or, are there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nzContent` API, `nzTitle` API and `nzFooter` API. They accept **templateRef** and **string** as input. using **templateRef** will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have done this:

`<nz-modal
  [(nzVisible)]="isVisible"
  nzTitle="Create relation"
  (nzOnCancel)="handleCancel()"
  (nzOnOk)="handleOk()">
    <ng-container *nzModalContent>
    <app-label-relation-create>
    </app-label-relation-create>
  </ng-container>
</nz-modal>`